# How to use variables in loop, for nested lists

Tags: python

I`am trying to extract some data from a sheet in excel 'recursos is the name of the page', I would like to not use the current for cycle any ideas?

```
celdas3=recursos['AN8':str(rsearch)+str(max_row)]   

for c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10 in celdas3:                
    var_3=[c1.value,c2.value,c3.value,c4.value,c5.value,c6.value,c7.value,c8.value,c9.value,c10.value]
    ex3.append(var_3)
    print(ex3)
```

And I would like to instead of use c1,c2,c3, etc use a variable. celdas3 is:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to unpack the list in the `for` loop:

```
for c in celdas3:                
    var_3 = [c1.value for c1 in c]
    ex3.append(var_3)
    print(ex3)
```

Comment: Thanks! It was the answer I was looking for,